# Installing Apache Superset on Windows Server 2019, and connecting Superset with MSSQL

Tags: apache-superset, windows-server-2019

How Apache Superset can be installed on Windows Server 2019? What are the steps and commands to use for installing this?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to enable Linux on Windows Server 2019. Follow the steps mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Besides this, you also might need to have Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio installed on your windows computer. You may install it following the steps here:

https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c++-14-required/

Once you have both these, run the following commands in the Linux terminal mentioned here to installing Apache Superset:

source: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch

sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev python3-pip libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev

python3 -m pip install virtualenv

python3 -m venv superset

. superset/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install apache-superset

superset db upgrade

#after running above command if you get dataclass module missing error: run the following command, and then give the above command again:

pip install dataclasses

export FLASK_APP=superset

superset fab create-admin

#provide credentials

superset load_examples

superset init

superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger

Now you should be able to access apache superset at:
http://127.0.0.1:8088/login/

If you want to connect apache superset with MSSQL database, then you need to follow the steps mentioned here to install ODBC driver first:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15